# Override Dynamic Data Lists

Tags: liferay-6

I create a hook on "html/portlet/dynamic_data_lists/view_records.jsp" and add the following src code:

```
if(!editable && DDLRecordSetPermission.contains(permissionChecker, recordSet.getRecordSetId(), ActionKeys.VIEW)){
                headerNames.add(StringPool.BLANK);
                row.addJSP("right", SearchEntry.DEFAULT_VALIGN, "/html/portlet/dynamic_data_lists/record_action.jsp");
            }
```

Now I get an additional column with the "view-option", if the permission for the DDL is set on "view".

Now the background color of the header-cell of this column is white and not grey like all other. Where can I change the color to grey?

Comment: Is this code added to view_records.jsp or you have modified code?

Comment: It means you are adding extra column in row, but header column wont be added. You have to add `headerNames.add(StringPool.BLANK);`  at line:57

Comment: As you see in the code snippet, I add the header line `headerNames.add(StringPool.BLANK);`, if I add the new column.

Comment: But, that need to be added before constructor call of SearchContainer

Comment: Many thx, I didn't think anything of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding extra column in row, but header column wont be added.

You have to add 
`headerNames.add(StringPool.BLANK):`
in existing code where header name list is defined to add extra header column.